# Force Lightbox/jQuery to rescan the DOM

Tags: jquery, html, lightbox

I have no real idea, neither the capability nor the time to check the source code, of how Lightbox (https://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/) works.

To me, it looks like when the HTML is fully rendered, Lightbox scans the DOM to find all the elements with certain attributes (data-lightbox in particular), and intercepts some events (like onclick) to do its businesses.

My question: I am filling some DIVs dynamically, and they will be filled with elements that should be handled by Lightbox, but when I click on them, nothing happens.

After trying and thinking, my only explanation is that Lightbox cannot "attach" itself to these new elements because nobody "launches" Lightbox after the dynamic DIV filling.

So, if I am at least partially correct about how Lightbox works, how can I force it to rescan the DOM to attach itself to the new, dynamically created elements?

Comment: It doesn't look like Lightbox has a method for reinitialising (or even destroying/initialising) so you might be out of luck. Are you stuck with Lightbox, or could you use something newer, such as Fancybox? If the former, perhaps you could wait until your dynamic `<div>`s have finished loading and *then* initialise Lightbox. **Edit:** just realised that Lightbox isn't manually initialised..! Looks like an examination of the source code may be necessary after all.

Comment: Here's a way of waiting until your dynamic content has loaded before appending the Lightbox script: https://jsfiddle.net/hp6qfe58/3/ is that a suitable workaround?

Comment: Wow, regardless of if it's suitable or not, I will learn a lot studying your code, thank you! From what I can see, it's perfectly suitable, now it's just a matter of studying it and make it work on my issue. Thank you again a lot for your time, really appreciated it!

Comment: I was just about to post an explanation of that JSFiddle, but I realised that I can't actually reproduce your problem - check out this other JSFiddle I just made: https://jsfiddle.net/6oy27mas/3/ - `Lightbox.js` is added normally, i.e. a `<script>` tag, yet when I add dynamic content, it still works. Maybe you're using an old version?

Comment: Your JSFiddle works indeed. I always download the latest version and I actually downloaded it just some days ago so yes, it should be updated. But thank you again, I will compare what I am doing with what you are doing :)